# Computing Quantiles for a column in R to subset

Tags: r

I have a data set with the following structure:

```
Name=c("a","b","c")
Amount_Spent=c(386407,213918,212006)
```

What I am trying to do is compute which quartile the `Amount_Spent` falls under for each name and assign the value to a new variable (column) `Quantiles`. I am not able to use any of the apply functions to get this result, can someone help please?

Thanks in advance,
Raoul

Comment: You want to compute quantiles for a single value? Rather not..so please provide a working example (looks like you're using a dataframe, right?)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `cut` and `quantile`.

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(name=letters , am.spent = rnorm(26))

# divide df$am.spent 
df$qnt<- cut(df$am.spent , breaks=quantile(df$am.spent),
                                    labels=1:4, include.lowest=TRUE)

 # check ranges
 tapply(df$am.spent , df$qnt , range)
```

---

First get the `quantile`
     quantile(df$am.spent)

```
#        0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
#-3.5888426 -0.6879445 -0.1461107  0.5835165  1.2030989
```

Then use `cut` to divide df$am.spent at specified cutpoints - we cut at the values of the quantiles. This is specified with the `breaks`argument

Comment: @user3548643; your welcome. Also, similar to jlhoward's answer below you can add the prob argument to the quantile function at the breaks argument to give finer cutpoints - also need to tweak the labels

Answer (score 1):

The answer you get depends on how finely you want to cut the quantiles. Do you want quartiles (25% increments), deciles (10% increments), percentiles (1% increments)???

I have a feeling there's an easier way to do this, but here's one approach.

```
df           <- data.frame(Name,Amount_Spent)
q            <- quantile(df$Amount_Spent,prob=seq(0,1,0.01))  # percentiles
# function to retrieve closest quantile for a given value.
get.quantile <- function(x)names(q)[which(abs(q-x)==min(abs(q-x)))]
# apply this function for all values in df$Amount_Spent
df$Quantile  <- sapply(df$Amount_Spent,get.quantile)
df
#   Name Amount_Spent Quantile
# 1    a       386407     100%
# 2    b       213918      50%
# 3    c       212006       0%
```

Here is a slightly more interesting example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Name=letters,Amount_Spent=runif(26,2e5,4e5))
q <- quantile(df$Amount_Spent,prob=seq(0,1,0.01))
df$Quantile <- sapply(df$Amount_Spent,get.quantile)
head(df)

#   Name Amount_Spent Quantile
# 1    a     253101.7      24%
# 2    b     274424.8      32%
# 3    c     314570.7      52%
# 4    d     381641.6      88%
# 5    e     240336.4      12%
# 6    f     379677.9      84%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was looking primarily at quantiles, but percentiles too would be good as would require that at some point. Appreciate your help!